# C# selenium unable to locate button through xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, htmlelements

I'm trying to locate an element using XPath but my code is incorrect and I'm not sure of the write syntax.

I entered the code below which isn't working.

```
IWebElement customizeButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]"));
```

The HTML code for the element is below

```
<button class="button u-space-ls js-customize-button button--primary " data-tooltip="{&quot;placement&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Customize&quot;}" data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.3"><span class="icon icon-gear" data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.3.0"></span><span class="u-small-hidden u-medium-hidden" data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.3.1"> Customize</span></button>
```

Can you please let me know how I should correct my code?

Thanks

Comment: and how shall we check this xpath without the html? you only showed us a button tag.

Comment: Can you provide the html ? Or maybe you can add an id to that element and it will be very simple to locate that element.

Comment: Note that using the suggested XPath is not recommended, as it's very brittle. Many small changes in the page can cause it to stop being correct. The rule of thumb is to rely on fewer details as possible that have high risk of changing (like the number of inner divs and their ordinal indices), as long as they identify the element uniquely. This is why Id is usually the preferred way if it's available and not auto generated. Class and *simple* CssSelectors are also fine as long as they follows that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to locate the button with text as **Customize** as the element is *JavaScript* enabled element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
IWebElement customizeButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='button u-space-ls js-customize-button button--primary']//span[@class='u-small-hidden u-medium-hidden']")));
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had to use the ClassName but this worked perfectly.  
      IWebElement customizeButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("js-customize-button")));