# no such element: Unable to locate element : {"method":"css selector","selector":"#Password"} using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wrote a simple test for login

```
namespace Seleniumtest.Customer
{
    [TestFixture]
    class LoginTest :TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void LoginWithPhoneNumber()
        {
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test123.ifc.ir/login");
            webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("EmailOrPhoneNumber")).SendKeys("09108599423");
            webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("buttons")).Click();
            var input = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));     
            Assert.That(input.Displayed, Is.True);
        }

    }
}
```

This program will click login and have login and find partial view input password but its just instert the value in username and click the submit but never find password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that on page one you have `username` and `clickable` button, and once you click on the button it will redirect you to a new page where you can provide the password.

However, this new page is not rendered properly and that's the reason you are getting

```
no such element: Unable to locate element : {"method":"css selector","selector":"#Password"}
```

In C#-Selenium bindings, you can use the `explicit wait` like below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement input = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.Id("Password")));
```

and now the input is a web element, you can input the password with `SendKeys` method.

```
input.SendKeys("your password");
```

[Reference link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Answer (score 1):

Once you invoke the url through *`get()`*, fillup the *EmailOrPhoneNumber* field and click on the *Submit* button it would need a little while for the *Password* field to be **visible** and **interactable**.

---

### Solution

In these cases to invoke *`Click()`* on the desired element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the [ElementToBeClickable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451578/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- *Id*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("Password"))).Click();
  ```
- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#Password"))).Click();
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='Password']"))).Click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [C# selenium unable to locate button through xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49576331/7429447)